# Class inheritance when using < ::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The REST API railscast has the following code example:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      class Product < ::Product
        def as_json(options={})
          super.merge(released_on: released_at.to_date)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble following what:

```
  class Product < ::Product
```

...does?  When I try to recreate something similar in irb I get:

```
module Fooirb(main):001:0> module Foobar
irb(main):002:1> class Product < ::Product
irb(main):003:2> end
irb(main):004:1> end
NameError: uninitialized constant Product
    from (irb):2:in `<module:Foobar>'
    from (irb):1
```

[screen casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `::` token indicates a namespace, and if used without anything directly before, it accesses the top-level namespace. So for example, take this small program:

```
class Bar
  def initialize
    puts "New ingot created"
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    def initialize(location)
      puts "New bar built in #{location}".
    end
  end

  def self.new_bar(which)
    if which == :top
      Bar.new("Rubytown, USA")
    else
      ::Bar.new
    end
  end
end
```

If you call `Foo.new_bar(:top)`, the message `New bar built in Rubytown, USA` gets printed. If instead you use, say, `Foo.new_bar(:place_to_drink)` it instead prints `New ingot created`".

Comment: I think your explanation (last sentence) should be reverse. If you call `Foo.new_bar(:top)`, it should print `"New bar built in Rubytown, USA"`

Comment: Ah, nice catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
class Product
end

module Foo
  class Product < ::Product
  end
end
```

The key is the namespace: you define the first Product in the global namespace (that is Object, so `Object::Product == ::Product` ) (like in javascript `foo = bar` is equal to `window.foo = bar`)

Instead, `module Foo; class Product` is in the module Foo scope, so is equal to `Foo::Product`. So you can write the previous example in this way:

```
class Object::Product
end

module Object::Foo
  class Object::Foo::Product < Object::Product
  end
end
```

The meaning is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The ::Product is looking in the top-level namespace for a Product class. In this case it's accessing the existing model. From the rails cast:

> What we’ll do is create a new Product class inside the ProductsController that inherits from our existing Product model class and make the changes there.

Answer (score 0):

< means inherit from

:: means namespace, but if begins with :: means without namespace

class Product < ::Product means class Product inherit from another class Product located outside current namespace

Answer (score 0):

About the error you have, don't use `irb` use `rails console` (IRB doesn't load rails app, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)